# Email Template IF Statement Formula

Tags: email-template, formula-field

I have this Email Template in Salesforce that is capturing information from the lead based on IF Statement conditions.

I understand that in order to use formulas on Email Templates I have to use the regular formula inside curly brackets "{!}".

**I have 2 fields for this matter:**
**Field 1:** It's a checkbox field - API = `Quote_Request_Upholstery_Cleaning__c`

**Field 2:** It's a regular number field (with 1 Decimal point) - API = `Quote_No_Bedrooms_HC__c`

The condition is as follow: If Field 1 is checked, show Field 2 value. If NOT checked, show nothing.

```
{!IF(Lead.Quote_Request_Upholstery_Cleaning__c = TRUE, Lead.Quote_No_Bedrooms_HC__c,'')}
```

Very straight forward, right? At least that's what I thought. This formula seems to work fine with regular text fields but not with number fields. It will not show the values at all. When I use the regular merge field `{!Lead.Quote_Request_Upholstery_Cleaning__c}` it shows the value without any problems.

Anyone to tell me what seems to be wrong here?
[image]
I'm attaching an image showing the formula. It's a fairly large template with many IF Statements with the same issue. It will work with regular text fields but not with number fields. I feel like if I solve this issue, I'll solve them all. Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: (1) the `= true` is unnecessary; (2) did you try wrapping the decimal fieldname with the `TEXT(..)` function?

Comment: +1 to  @crop1645 feature. I think that because of returned types are different, it 'tries' to cast it to text, but do it bad way in case of number. But i can not confirm that according to documentation. About a lot of ifs -- I would recommend you to make single if <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Lead.Quote...__c}" layout="none"> panel, put all the content inside, that should be rendered. Save a lot of formula fixes )

Comment: @kurunve -- outputPanel assumes email template is VF - but it isn't as `relatedTo` isn't used; but your suggestion is good

Comment: @crop1645 my bad, but similar approach <div style="display:{!Lead.Quote_Request_Upholstery_Cleaning__c,'block','none' "> ... </div> as alternate solution may do the trick as well. (or span instead of a div, or another property like visibility etc)

Answer (score 1):

It turned not being a syntax issue. Prior to posting this question, I should have thought about building a test formula field, which I ended up doing so.

The correct syntax would be:

```
{!IF(Lead.Quote_Request_Upholstery_Cleaning__c = TRUE, Lead.Quote_No_Bedrooms_HC__c, NULL)}
```